# Почему не вызываются методы объекта из arraylist с помощью stream (кроме toString)?

Tags: java, потоки-данных, arraylist, java-stream

Целый день пытаюсь разобраться с `java stream`, но не могу понять одной вещи.

Есть класс `SomeClass`, в нем есть переопределенный `public String toString()` и есть другие методы, например, `public void someMethod()`.

Далее, есть `ArrayList` экземпляров этого класса и Stream:

```java
List<SomeClass> someList = new ArrayList<>();
Stream someStream = someList.stream();
```

Если я пытаюсь с помощью `stream.filter` вызвать `toString()`, он вызывается, а если пытаюсь вызвать любой другой метод, то он не доступен.

Так как же вызывать другие методы?!

Вот мой класс `SomeClass`:

```
public class SomeClass {
    String name;

    SomeClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public void someMethod(){
        System.out.println("someMethod()" + name);
    }
}
```

Вот класс с методом `main()`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<SomeClass> someList = new ArrayList<>();
        someList.add(new SomeClass("A"));
        someList.add(new SomeClass("B"));
        Stream someStream = someList.stream();
        someStream.filter(x -> "A".equals(x.toString())).forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.toString())); //работает
        someStream.filter(x -> "A".equals(x.toString())).forEach(x -> x.someMethod()); //someMethod() не доступен
        someStream.filter(x -> "A".equals(x.getName())).forEach(x -> x.someMethod()); //getName() тоже не доступен
    }
}
```

**Ошибка:**

> Cannot resolve method 'someMethod' in 'Object'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Интерфейс `Stream<T>`, так же как и интерфейсы коллекций `Collection<T>`, `List<T>`, `Set<T>` являются обобщёнными, а в объявлении:

```java
Stream someStream = someList.stream();
```

для экземпляра потока `someStream` не указан тип объектов, то есть он объявлен как "сырой" (компилятор должен был показать соответствующее предупреждение), а значит, при обработке элементов в этом потоке они обрабатываются как простые объекты, у которых существуют только методы `toString`, `hashCode`, `equals` и т.п.

Для решения этой проблемы достаточно правильно объявить поток:

```java
Stream<SomeClass> someStream = someList.stream();
```

Но даже при корректном объявлении повторное использование потока указанным способом не будет работать, так как после первого же использования (вызова терминального метода типа `forEach`) поток будет закрыт, и соответственно будет выброшено исключение `java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed`.

Если нужно использовать один поток несколько раз, понадобится определить его `Supplier`, и вызывать поток при помощи `Supplier::get`:

```java
import java.util.function.Supplier;
// ...

List<SomeClass> someList = new ArrayList<>();
someList.add(new SomeClass("A"));
someList.add(new SomeClass("B"));
Supplier<Stream<SomeClass>> someStream = () -> someList.stream();
someStream.get().filter(x -> "A".equals(x.toString())).forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.toString())); //работает
someStream.get().filter(x -> "A".equals(x.toString())).forEach(SomeClass::someMethod);
someStream.get().map(SomeClass::getName).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Или же можно просто каждый раз вызывать метод `stream` у списка `someList`, соответственно, проблем с типизацией также не будет:

```java
List<SomeClass> list = Arrays.asList(new SomeClass("A"), new SomeClass("B"));

list.stream().filter(x -> "A".equals(x.toString())).forEach(System.out::println);
List<String> names = list.stream().map(SomeClass::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно.